# How to do insert and update on the same view page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert

My problem is insert and update are working fine when i am doing seperately..but when i do the insert in presence of update button i am getting null values..How can i do insert and update on the same view page..
Controller code for insert:

```
 public function insert($id='')
{
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

            $dc=$this->input->post('dc');
            if($dc=='c'){
            $amount=$this->input->post('credit1');
                        } 
            else if ($dc=='d') {
            $amount=$this->input->post('debit');
                                }

$data=array(
      'date' =>$this->input->post('TDate'),
      'code' =>$this->input->post('TName'),
      'project' =>$this->input->post('TName1'),
      'part' =>$this->input->post('part1'),
      'part1' =>$this->input->post('part2'),
      'dc'=>$this->input->post('dc'),
      'amount'=>$amount,
   );

$this->db->insert('daybook',$data);
 $this->session->set_flashdata('Add', 'Inserted Successfully');
 redirect('BookKeeping/daybook','refresh');
}
```

Controller code for update:

```
public function update($id='')
{

      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        echo "<pre>";var_dump($id);
            $dc=$this->input->post('dc');
            if($dc=='c'){
            $amount=$this->input->post('credit1');
                        } 
            else if ($dc=='d') {
            $amount=$this->input->post('debit');
                                }

$data=array(
      'date' =>$this->input->post('TDate'),
      'code' =>$this->input->post('TName'),
      'project' =>$this->input->post('TName1'),
      'part' =>$this->input->post('part1'),
      'part1' =>$this->input->post('part2'),
      'dc'=>$this->input->post('dc'),
      'amount'=>$amount,
   );
$this->db->where('recno', $_POST['id']);
$this->db->update('daybook', $data);
$this->session->set_flashdata('Add1', 'Updated Successfully'); 
redirect('BookKeeping/daybook','refresh');
}
```

View page for both insert and update:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-xs datepicker-dates" placeholder="Pick a date&hellip;" id="TDate" name="TDate"value="<?php if(!empty($result) && !empty($result['date'])){ echo $result['date']; } ?>" required="">

                                    <input type="text"  id="TAmt" class="form-control input-xs qty" name="part1" style="width: 370px;" placeholder="Particulars" required value="<?php if(!empty($result) && !empty($result['part'])){ echo $result['part']; } ?>">

                                    <input type="text"  id="TAmt" class="form-control input-xs qty" name="part2" style="width: 370px;" placeholder="Particulars" required value="<?php if(!empty($result) && !empty($result['part'])){ echo $result['part1']; } ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass last insert id redirect via ('BookKeeping/daybook'.$last_insert_id')

Insert query :

```
  $this->db->insert('daybook',$data);
  $this->session->set_flashdata('Add', 'Inserted Successfully');
  redirect('BookKeeping/daybook/'.$last_insert_id,'refresh');
```

Update query: update id

```
$this->db->where('recno', $_POST['id']);
$this->db->update('daybook', $data);
$this->session->set_flashdata('Add1', 'Updated Successfully'); 
redirect('BookKeeping/daybook/'.$_POST['id'],'refresh');
```

Get id in daybook function and use select query get data to pass view file.
example :

```
 function daybook($id= "")
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('daybook');
        $this->db->where('recno', $_POST['id']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $data['result'] = $result;
    $this->load->view('daybook', $data['result']);
    }
```

It may help you.

Comment: send me to print $result result in the view page.

Comment: Array
(
    [recno] => 95
    [date] => 05/12/2018
    [code] => 
    [project] => 
    [part] => about 
    [part1] => jokes
    [amount] => 10
    [dc] => c
    [ledreno] => 0
    [vouno] => 0
    [pvouno] => 
    [type] => 
    [mark] => 
    [slno] => 
    [shift] => 
    [pacno] => 0
)                                                                                          this is my $result for first page

Comment: i don't get error in this..But i am getting null values when i try to insert the values because i specified null the value when the record no is not present..so null occurs i don't know how to specify for insert values

Comment: Error Number: 1048

Column 'date' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `daybook` (`date`, `code`, `project`, `part`, `part1`, `dc`, `amount`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)..this is the error when i try to insert

Comment: Ok bro.you check required fields in view page or you check not empty in controllter.Try this 
EX: $date = (!empty($this->input->post('date')) ? $this->input->post('date') : '' ;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184994/discussion-between-dhara-and-r-surya).

Answer (score 0):

in which array your data is coming.use that array like this: try this i hope it will help you.

```
<?php echo isset($arrayName) ? "Update" : "Add"; ?>

<input name="part" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($arrayName) && isset($arrayName['part']) ? $arrayName['part'] : '' ?>" id="part" placeholder="part">
```

Comment: not a function name.in which array you are getting data by id.it is that array.

Comment: okey... I am getting update values from the $result array but i don't have any array for insert

Comment: in your controller use check for id.if($id!=''){
updatequery
}
else{
insert query
}